# Imageview skipped Frames

Tags: android, imageview

i've got a Static Page in a Framework. My Navigation Drawer skip frames, when i'm loading the pictures the first time. Now just 3.

Like that:
-Title
-Image (1000px x 350px, 50kb)
-Text

I want to use more Pictures in this Page but doens't think this will look good, because i have skipping Frames on the Nexus 4 and want this App to run also on Low End Devices.

I set the Images in the XML-File. Is there a better way to do this? AsyncTask

Got it myself. Hope i can help anybody with this Problem in the future :)

```
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//This is updated to load the images before setting them
            final Drawable res_befree = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sc_befreejpg);
            final Drawable res_morepower = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sc_morepower);
            final Drawable res_savemoney = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sc_savemoney);
            final Drawable res_lifequality = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sc_lifequality);
```

> //Update End
>
> ```
>         getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>             @Override
>             public void run() {
>
>                 // This code will always run on the UI thread, therefore is safe to modify UI elements.
>                 ProgressBar pb_befree = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pb_befree);
>                 ImageView befree = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.befree);
>                 befree.setImageResource(R.drawable.sc_befreejpg);
>                 pb_befree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>                 befree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>             }
>         });
>
>
>         return "All Done!";
>     }}
> ```

Have to put this in my Fragment. Now Images are loading and then set in the UI. UI runs without skipping frames.

Comment: Thought this will solve my Problem but i think the Image loading is still running on the main thread... Anypne has a better idea?

Comment: Edited my code. This is the solution i looked for. UI Thread doesn't skip Frames now, Imageload in Async Task, and settings Images in Asynctask with runonUIThread().