# background images causing frames to be skipped

Tags: java, android

I have a very simple app with just a `TextView` and a `Button` inside of a `RelativeLayout` (with a background image):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image" >

    <!-- text in top left of background -->
    <TextView android:text="App" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- primary button that outputs audio -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="trueButtonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `onClick` event just plays some audio:

```
public void trueButtonClick(View v) {
    //create media player
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_test);
    //make noise
    mp.start();
}
```

In logcat, I get these messages:

```
03-02 23:41:40.063    1910-1910/com.example.mohammad.trueapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set 
03-02 23:41:40.063    1910-1910/com.example.mohammad.trueapp I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 210 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-02 23:41:43.961    1910-1910/com.example.mohammad.trueapp I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 232 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 
03-02 23:45:05.506    1910-1910/com.example.mohammad.trueapp I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 
03-02 23:45:07.279    1910-1910/com.example.mohammad.trueapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set 
03-02 23:45:07.323    1910-1910/com.example.mohammad.trueapp I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 
03-02 23:45:10.490    1910-1910/com.example.mohammad.trueapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
```

When I remove the background image `@drawable/background_image`, the application speeds up. However, after adding the background image, the application is so slow that it seems broken from the user's perspective. The background image size is 1040x851. Is there a way I can speed this up to prevent the drastic lag?

Comment: did you added hardware accelerated=true in your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: @Rustam I just did that. There wasn't too much of a difference. Also, from what I understand, this wouldn't help on older Android phones.

Comment: Do you have your image scaled for different resolutions in `drawable-?dpi` folders? This would optimize the image loading.

Comment: @Lamorak I do not. Do I have to manually resize them? Do I have to select which image to use in the Java side or the XML side?

Comment: When you reference `@drawable/image` android automatically picks the best image for current resolution. If the best image doesn't match android will resize it if the scale is provided. (don't store in `drawable` or `drawable-nodpi`) :) See [this documantation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Comment: But is is of course a good practice to resize the images manually if you want to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are loading a big size image. Try to optimize the resolution of it.

1px = 4 byte memory

Through this you can come to know how much your app is taking the memory

Comment: What would be the smallest size that would still look fine on the largest screen size? I don't want the quality of the image to degrade on large screen sizes

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565127/imageview-skipped-frames this guy tried loading the image in asyntask, it worked for him