# Android - Loading drawables without skipping frames

Tags: android, xml, drawable

Okay, so I am using a drawable PNG (1200 x 1920, 30kb) as a background in an activity. A snippet of my XML code is shown below. My problem is the application is skipping frames and has lagged responses. Could anybody tell me why this is happening, or a good way to solve my problem? I still would like to be able to use this PNG file as the background. Thanks

XML Snippet:

```css
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/MY_PNG_BACKGROUND"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Logcat message:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Things I have looked at:

- [Imageview skipped frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565127/imageview-skipped-frames) (This may work for me if someone can tell me how to do it in XML instead of programmatically in Java)
- [background images causing frames to be skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824334/background-images-causing-frames-to-be-skipped)

Comment: "Could anybody tell me why this is happening" -- decoding an 9MB image is not going to be quick (where the 9MB refers to the amount of heap space used). Not only will that take a moment on its own, but it may be triggering one or more `GC_FOR_ALLOC` calls to free up memory to be able to handle the image. Plus, since you elected to put this in a drawable resource, Android may be resampling the image to deal with screen density differences. And, to top it off, the vast majority of Android devices have lower-resolution screens and cannot make use of such a large, high-resolution image.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the PNG mentioned is meant for tablet views. Would the only solution be to have a smaller/less resolution background? @CommonsWare

Comment: I recommend that you first confirm the exact nature of the problem, such as by using Android Studio to do a method trace and see where you are spending your time. 53 frames is nearly a full second taken up on the main application thread. Then, look for other LogCat messages immediately preceding your `Choreographer` one (e.g., `GC_FOR_ALLOC`) to try to determine if that's part of your problem. You *might* try pre-loading this image on a background thread, though I have never tried that for a resource. Also, make sure this resource is in `res/drawable-nodpi/` or `res/drawable-anydpi/`.

Comment: Okay, I have been having quite a bit of trouble with graphics so I might look into pre-loading the images. If you happen to know a good way to do this and want to put it in an answer I can mark it as correct. Thanks for the help @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help from CommonsWare in the comments, I was able to figure this out. I pre-loaded the drawable in my java class in the background using AsyncTask. Here is a code example:

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Calling the task to be done in the background, in this case loading the drawable
        new LoadDrawable().execute();

    }

    private class LoadDrawable extends AsyncTask<Drawable, Void, Drawable> {
        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(Drawable... params) {
            //Loading the drawable in the background
            final Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
            //After the drawable is loaded, onPostExecute is called
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable loaded) {
            //Hide the progress bar
            ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Set the layout background with your loaded drawable
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
            layout.setBackgroundDrawable(loaded);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but still there is very much noticeable lag