# Background image causing lag and frame skipping

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-image

I have a simple layout in which I want a background image. First I tried to put the background image through xml but there was very much lag.

So I followed [Set image through AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107914/android-loading-drawables-without-skipping-frames#_=_) but still no luck.

Image is of 1131 X 1800 resolution and size is 369kb.

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Java File

```
public class MainActivity extends flights{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new LoadDrawable().execute();
}

private class LoadDrawable extends AsyncTask<Drawable, Void, Drawable> {
    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Drawable... params) {
        //Loading the drawable in the background
        final Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.as);
        //After the drawable is loaded, onPostExecute is called
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable loaded) {
        //Hide the progress bar
        //ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        //progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Set the layout background with your loaded drawable
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(loaded);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your image size is big. a problem in set image to background is size of image and not fit resolution. i had same problem. after search and test many methods, i found glide is a good library to set a image. with this library, its not important what your device size is. the glide will set it.

for set image from your drawable, you can code like this:

```
 Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.backtwo).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(size.x, size.y) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resource);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    iv_background.setBackground(drawable);
                }
            }
        });
```

another approach is using different image resolution for different device screen. weakness of this approach is increasing apk size

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that onPostExecute() happens on the main thread and thus can cause what you are seeing (but you have no workaround here).

As for your problem, the image is not that big so it seems as if it shouldn't cause this kind of issue; however, it might be worth testing what happens if you replace it to a smaller image (BTW, it is better to have an image with even resolutions - 1131 is a bad number here).

Another option is to decode the bitmap (which is time consuming) inside the async task -

```
private class LoadDrawable extends AsyncTask<Drawable, Void, Drawable> {
    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Drawable... params) {
        return new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.as)); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried my way with 1125 X 1442 resolution image of size 12.14kb. And there is same lag and skipping frame.

P.S
I am using a .animate function which is rotating a very small image on click. When I choose a color as background then there is no problem of lag but I do so with image as background then there is lag.

Comment: Also tried with BitmapDrawable which you referred but still same issue.

Comment: Did you try without the animation?

Comment: Just did, no luck.